# Python test whole script

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, testing, automated-tests

I have a Python script. I use `unittest` for tests, but how can I test whole script.

My idea is something like this:

```
def test_script(self):
    output=runScript('test.py --a 5 --b 3')
    self.assertEqual(output, '8')
```

test.py takes argument a and b and print a+b, in this case 8

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) library to call a script and capture the output.

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(
    ['./test.py', '--a', ...],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
)

print p.stdout.read()
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is what you wanted, use python unittest to wrap up the blackbox testing

```
import unittest # install and import
```

wrap your test in TestCase

```
class ScriptTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_script(self):
        output=runScript('test.py --a 5 --b 3')
        self.assertEqual(output, '8')
```

add TestCase to unittest

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(ScriptTest)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```